# HttpContext.Current.Session null item

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i'm storing in HttpContext.Current.Session current user, SiteUser is single-tone class that presents current active siteuser, and when he logged i'm creating new SiteUser() in controller and in constructor adding him to the session:

```
public static SiteUser Create()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] = new SiteUser();

    return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] as SiteUser;
}
```

then, with every request to the server services i'm check is user available in session:

```
public static SiteUser Current
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null || HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] == null)
        {
            throw new SiteUserAutorizationExeption();
        }

        return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] as SiteUser;
    }
}
```

otherwise i'm generate non-auth-user exception and redirect him to the logon page. 
but sometimes HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] is null, but HttpContext.Current.Session doesn't null and FormsAuthenticationTicket is available and Expired property is also false. 
can somebody help me, why HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] can be null?

**UPD**: webconfig session settings: `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />`

**UPD**: sessionKey is: `public const string sessionKey = "SiteUser";`

**UPD2**: i'm forget to add, that in session also stored Culture settings:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Culture"]
```

and when exception hits, that HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] is null, culture-item isn't

**UPD3**: i have downloaded symbol tables of source .NET Framework and set breakpoints at SessionStateItemCollection on changing collection items. and i resolved some mistakes:
1) all collection items are null — "culture" is setting up after
2) it happens at the session end event
i can't understand how it can be, because at web.config session timeout is set 20

Comment: Is it in-memory session? or is configured to persist to a database? Also : is IIS perhaps recycling the app-pool?

Comment: mmm.. i'm using InProc session mode, is it mean that session is in-memory?  is IIS perhaps recycling the app-pool - i don't sure, currently i'm run at asp.net development server

Comment: I don't the the dev server will recycle - that is an IIS thing

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Daniel, yes. the real problem was in IIS cache settings. under high load it can cache cookies with sessions

Comment: Did you do something special to solve this? Sometimes, I have the same problem on debug on my local machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sessionKey may be changing, you probably only need to do:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"]
```

Or the session may be expiring, check the timeout:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(VS.71).aspx

Or you may be setting the session value from somewhere else, normally i control access to Session/Context object through one property

```
static readonly string SESSION_CurrentUser = "CurrentUser";

public static SiteUser Create() {     
 SiteUser.Current = new SiteUser();      
 return SiteUser.Current;
}

public static SiteUser Current {     
 get {         
  if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null || HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_CurrentUser] == null) {             
   throw new SiteUserAutorizationExeption();         
  }          
  return HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_CurrentUser] as SiteUser;     
 } 
 set {
  if (!HttpContext.Current.Session == null) {
   HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_CurrentUser] = value;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: yes, my sessionKey is const string value. i'm forget to add information about this to the topic. i will try to set in property, this is good idea, thanks