# Session variable remaining null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project and in it I need to pass a variable between views. I'm trying to do this using a session variable but it stays null when I try to set it. What am I doing wrong? All of this code is in my controller.

```
 public string searchQ
    {
        get { return (string)Session["searchQ"]; }
        set { Session["searchQ"] = ""; }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Session["InitialLoad"] = "Yes";
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string heatSearch)
    {
        ViewBag.SearchKey = heatSearch;
        searchQ= heatSearch;
        return View();
    }



    public ActionResult Index_Perm()
    {
        ViewBag.SearchKey = searchQ;

        return View();
    }
```

The goal is to pass that search key between the views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your property setter.

```
public string searchQ
{
    get { return (string)Session["searchQ"]; }
    set { Session["searchQ"] = ""; }
}
```

This will always assign the session variable an empty string.

It should look like this:

```
public string searchQ
{
    get { return (string)Session["searchQ"]; }
    set { Session["searchQ"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. One more thing, when I click the link to to load the page Index_Perm, searchQ is null again.

Comment: @Danger_Fox AFAIK, that should fix it, but this question offers a number of tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629882/asp-net-mvc-session-is-null