# MVC 5 Session is Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

The session is always Null inside of my controller in MVC 5. Accessing it via Controller or HttpContext it is still null. I have read also read the post like the one below where you can add the sessionState module to the web config but that does not work for me. Any ideas?

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session


Controller.Session
```

[ASP.NET MVC - Session is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629882/asp-net-mvc-session-is-null)

Comment: where in your controller?

Comment: Can you share more details about your project and controller code. I created a new MVC app in VS2012 and can see Session.SessionID and HttpContext.Session.SessionID is returning successfully in AccountController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the web.config the sessionState was set to Off. I changed it to InProc and the session is no longer null

Comment: Could you please let us know where you put it in the web.config?
I put `<sessionState timeout="120" mode="InProc"  />` in the `<system.web>` with no success!