# Session is not persisting in some machine, while working fine in other machines

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies, session-state

In my ASP.Net MVC application, I have stored some information in Session.

When I am running the application locally, the session values are persisting but when I deploy that in to the server & trying to access the *application is throwing Null exception* as **session values are not persisting between server requests.**

Today I found the same behavior in another dev machine too. :|

I am using only this line in web.config to achieve this ...

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="25"></sessionState>
```

I have referred (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725624(v=ws.10).aspx) and verified the configurations & everything looks fine.

Can it happen due to some difference in cookie settings or any configuration changes I need to do in App pool / IIS settings?

An early response on the possible reasons would be a great help.

Thanks...

Comment: Show me your `sessionState` on your `Web.config` please

Comment: <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="25"></sessionState>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629882/asp-net-mvc-session-is-null